# format and informat in sas

Tags: format, sas, informat

I have the following data:

```
data d;
input date1 $ date2 $;
cards;
5oct10  11nov11
6jul12  12oct13
1jan08  4may10
4may04  8jul06
1mar07  5aug07
18may04 1oug09
7aug05  8jul09
1feb03  5apr06
3feb01  15jul08
4apr07 16apr07
run;
```

*I need to read this in a date7.informat and then present the data on date9.format.

*how do I do I read the data to begin with on a  width format, and how do I convert the date's width from 7 to 9 while my cars are not completely numeric?

when trying something like that:

```
proc print data=d;
format date1 date2 date9.;;
run;
```

it fails since I use a numeric format on a none-completely numeric var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an INFORMAT statement to tell SAS how to read the variables then you do not not need to list a format in the INPUT statement. The INFORMAT and the FORMAT for a variable do not need to be the same, but in this case they can be because the DATE9 informat will recognize a value with only a two digit year.

```
informat date1 date2 date9.;
format date1 date2 date9.;
input date1 date2 ;
```

Comment: Thank you! , this is the way it worked out best: data d;
informat date1 date2 date7.;
format date1 date2 date9.;
input date1 date2 ;
cards;
5oct10  11nov11
6jul12  12oct13
1jan08  4may10
4may04  8jul06
1mar07  5aug07
18may04 1aug09
7aug05  8jul09
1feb03  5apr06
3feb01  15jul08
4apr07 16apr07
run;

Answer (score 1):

```
data d;
input date1 date7.  date2 date7.;
format date1 date9. date2 date9.;
cards;
5oct10  11nov11
6jul12  12oct13
1jan08  4may10
4may04  8jul06
1mar07  5aug07
18may04 1oug09
7aug05  8jul09
1feb03  5apr06
3feb01  15jul08
4apr07 16apr07
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your data step such that:

```
input date1 date7. date2 date7.;
```

If you use `date1 $` to read the datelines, your resulted dataset would have the value for date1 =  `'5oct10','6jul12' and so on`. However, when you apply the format `date9.` at `proc print`, you need to supply a SAS time value. Please note that SAS read time value in its own format  i.e. counting from 01/Jan/1960. You could try it by running the statement `put "today is today()" at your SAS.

And your proc print statement should work perfectly after the modification.

And, for some reason(s) you want to read the value of date1 and date2 in its own format i.e. `5oct10`, I am afraid you may need to separate the value day, month, and year respectively( e.g. by `scan` function) and use the function `MDY( month, day, year)` to turn it into a SAS time value. Your format statement with  `date7.` at `proc print` statement would also work in this case.